# Windows Forms vs ASP.NET to create a Data Maintenance program

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am creating a application which is mainly used inside a office for data maintenance. It will be used to store data like work list, future works, reminders etc .All data will be presented to user in the form of grids. So it's all about data stored in SQL server database. There will be number of users accessing it and they modify data frequently. Also there will be so many options like an ERP program.There is no connection to internet is required for this program.

So in this case which programming language is better? Should I choose WinForms or ASP.NET? The main concentration to choose between this will be performance, ease of use, also it should support more function for grid controls etc. So which one should I choose? And what will be the advantage and disadvantage of both?

Comment: `VB.NET` is a language. `ASP.NET` is a Web application framework designed for Web development. You would use `VB.NET` to code within an `ASP.NET` application in the same way that you could use `C#`. Are you referring to the use of `WinForms` over `ASP.NET`?

Comment: ok..Yes i am referring to Winforms over ASP.net.Let me edit question also

Comment: Take a look at some previous answers, they may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281555/asp-net-and-winforms, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020043/asp-net-verses-winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers:

**WinForms**

Good

- No webserver to install, setup and secure

Bad

- Installation of some kind required on each machine e.g .NET framwork, exe, assemblies, etc.
- More difficult to rollout updates to the application

**ASP.NET**

Good

- No installation on clients required
- Can run on machines other than windows including mobile devices
- Updates to the application can be published instantly to all clients

Bad

- Have to use IIS or UltiDev Web Server to serve up pages
- File system is more secure so reading and writing to files can be time consuming to configure

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use jQuery and Javascript to add additional functionality to the Standard ASP.NET GridView I would say a Windows Form would be more suited, depending on the size of the data it will most likely offer better performance and you have much more control over the actual functionality of the program, rather than dealing with browser related restraints.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a question for this forum... VB.Net is a Language and ASP.Net is a Framework. Do you mean should I create a client windows app or a web (intranet) app then this would depend on your strengths as the intranet option would also require HTML and possibly CSS/Javascript.